# vb.net <> or IsNot not working correctly

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net application, where i use this code:

```
If first_letter <> "" Or first_letter <> "Pending" Then

End If
```

but it doesn't seem to be working, if i MsgBox(first_letter) above this if statement i get `Pending`

So this means it should not be running what is inside this if statement but it does

I have also tried `IsNot` in place of `<>` but it still does the same thing

Is there any reason its running the code inside the if, even though `first_letter` is equal to `Pending`

Comment: its a letter as in letter to post, not a single character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `"Pending"` matches already the first condition because it is `<> ""`.

Use `AndAlso` instead of `Or`:

```
If first_letter <> "" AndAlso first_letter <> "Pending" Then

End If
```

Note that you should use `OrElse` and `AndAlso` instead of `Or` and `And` because those are short-circuiting operators. That means that they don't evaluate the second condition if the first is already `True`/`False`. This can be important if you have something like:

```
Dim first_letter As String = Nothing
If first_letter IsNot Nothing AndAlso first_letter.StartsWith("P") Then 

End If
```

This throws an exception if you use `And` instead of `AndAlso`.

Answer (score 1):

The condition will always be true. Whatever string the variable contains, it will either be different from an empty string or different from the string `"Pending"`.

If the variable contains `"Pending"`, then it will be different from an empty string, and the first part of the condition is true.

You should use the `And` operator instead:

```
If first_letter <> "" And first_letter <> "Pending" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Condition is wrong here. You have used `Or` operator. Just replace `Or` with `And`